# DocBook XSL (FO) - Preventing pages to end with title element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm generating a document from DocBook5 using the DocBook-XSL stylesheets (with a heavy customisation layer).  However, in far too many places, pages end on section titles, which looks really bad in print.

Problem:  I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent page-breaks after section titles.

I can get it so that I always break before titles (a solution I discarded because the end result looked even worse in print.  Works well for web-release though), but can't figure out how to do it *only* if it's the last thing on a page.

My DocBook workflow:

1. `xmllint` takes the DocBook 5 sources, validates them and flattens it all out to a giant xml file with all includes resolved and baked in.
2. `saxon` takes the output from `xmllint` and combines it with the [doxbook-xsl stylesheets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/) to spit out a massive xsl-fo file that averages at 2kB per line of continuous magic.
3. The resulting xsl-fo is then fed through Apache `fop` to produce the final PDFs.

Comment: There are some (including me) who are not familiar with DocBook, but know XSLT and XSL-FO well. Can you include some code so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I could, if I knew what would at all be relevant.  It'd be hard to reproduce it without including all of the docbook stylesheets, my own customisation layer as well as the source for the actual document.  I could add the general XML document outline and a comment where the issue is, but I doubt that'd be useful to anyone.

Comment: I understand your point, but then it's difficult to help you I'm afraid. At least say what a section title looks like, that is, show its XSL-FO code.

Comment: Also which FO processor are you using and have you tested more than one?

Comment: @KevinBrown Budget constraints limit me to Apache FOP, so no, no others have been tested (because I wouldn't be able to use them in production).

Comment: You may wish to test also against a trial of RenderX. I would be surprised in the Docbook styles did not already set keeps on headings. It is possible that FOP is not respecting them.

Comment: @KevinBrown Right, fair enough.  The XEP trial will aid in debugging I suppose, I'll get on that asap.  Almost hoping that it's an issue in the DocBook stylesheets rather than FOP...I can always hack the stylesheets and send a pull request to the project.  I have no idea where to even begin looking in the FOP codebase (also, I'm even more rubbish at Java than I am XSL).

Answer (score 1):

You do not show any code, so I can only answer in very general terms.

What if you imposed a specific keep on the section title elements? If they are blocks,

```
<fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always">
```

Read up on this in the [XSL specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#keep-with-next).